# ruby compare string with file contents

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

My end goal is to compare values from a file to the records I’m pulling back from a database.

I have a text file with the following structure:

```
123,55,66
555,99,109
324,100,800
467,200,300
```

I then pull back records from a database and loop through them one by one.

```
sth.fetch do |row|
  validate = "#{row[0]},#{row[20]},#{row[21]}"
  names = File.readlines('results.txt')
  matches = names.select { |name| name[/#{validate}/i] }
  p "Result matches as expected: #{matches}"
end
```

so validate builds me the same format string as per the examples above... I then read all lines of the file and move them into an array and then compare. So this is great it gives me all matches but doesn't tell me rows that don't exist on the file?

So alternatively I tried

```
    sth.fetch do |row|
      File.open('results') do |f|
        f.each_line do |line|
          if line == validate
            puts "detail: #{line}"
          else
            puts "detail: #{validate}"
          end
        end
      end
end
```

But this then reads each line for every row and compares so it half achieves what I am after.

So I want to take my 'validate' string and read the contents of the file to see if a row matches and then print out it's a match. Alternatively if I pull back a record and it doesn't match the file then I just want one does not match message.

Thanks

Comment: Using `names = File.readlines('results.txt')` or `File.open('results')` in a loop is a bad idea because it's wasting CPU/disk time. Read the data outside the loop then access the variable inside the loop. `File.foreach(...)` is easier and clearer than `File.open(...) do |f| f.each_line do ...`

Comment: How big are the files being read? Do you have more files that are hits than misses, or the opposite, or an even spread?

Comment: Fairly even spread and they are in the low hundreds currently so nothing too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following

```
 names = File.readlines('results.txt').map(&:chomp) 
 sth.fetch do |row|
   validate = "#{row[0]},#{row[20]},#{row[21]}"

    # for direct compare
    # if names.include?(validate)
    # Or for Regexp
    if names.grep(/#{validate}/i).any?
      p "Result matches as expected: #{matches}" 
    else
      p "Result does not matches as expected: #{matches}" 
    end  
 end

 all_matches.uniq!
```